# Hide unused nodes after filtering

Tags: nodes, gephi

To create separate models for separate years (year is an attribute in the edges table), I am trying to use filters. Using the filter

> Attribute > Equal > year *string (Edge)*

I am able to hide edges that are not from that year. However, that leaves me with unconnected nodes (see image for explanation).

Is there any way to filter these (without removing nodes/edges that are relevant to the year-filter)? I am using Gephi 0.9.1.

[image: Image of the model, including unused nodes.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the filters to query for a degree range that starts in `1` instead of `0` :

> Overview > Filters > Library > Topology > Degree Range

If you want to save it as a graph you might want to use the 'visible only' option. Hope it helps